# How do I make a c++ makefile on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

Hello im trying to make a simple makefile for c++ on MacOS

I want to compile a code that uses these libraries

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <portaudio.h>
```

Im trying to use this makefile but I don't know how to add the libraries.

```
.PHONY: all clean

CC:= clang++

CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion -O2


SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.d,$(SOURCES))

all: main

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) main

-include $(DEPENDS)

# Make object files
%.o: %.cpp Makefile
    $(CC) $(WARNING) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@

# Linking the executable from the object files
main: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    ./main
```

Comment: Not sure about portaudio, but rest are C++ headers. BTW, use `cstdlib` instead of `stdlib.h` and `cstdio` instead of `stdio.h`.

Comment: @kiner_shah it looks like I get a red line under the code if I use cstdlib

Comment: Try running the makefile and see if it throws error on that line, it shouldn't really.

Comment: @kiner_shah Ahh yea it looks fine but I think I have a problem with the portaudio.h library.

Comment: Find the location of this file and add `-I folder_path` to compilation options.

Comment: @kiner_shah the library is located at:
`/usr/local/include/portaudio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include/portaudio.h
/usr/local/include/portaudio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include/portaudio.h`

where do I add it, in the make file?

Comment: Add `-I /usr/local/include/` to `CFLAGS`.

Comment: @kiner_shah so like this? `CFLAGS = -I /usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/19.7.0/include/`

Comment: No, like this `CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated-enum-enum-conversion -O2 -I /usr/local/include`.

Comment: @kiner_shah it looks like Im still getting an error: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Conventions matter.  A lot.  `CC` is the C compiler. `CXX` is the C++ compiler.  `CFLAGS` describes flags for the C- compiler.  `CXXFLAGS` is used by the C++ compiler.  You should not be using CC or CFLAGS at all.

Comment: @nobrainstudent, find in your system if you have library files for portaudio. If yes, then add a line `LDFLAGS = -L library_directory_path -lportaudio` something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't necessarily about your Makefile, as you said you get a red line. That's your IDE. So what you do is going to depend upon your IDE.

Part of the problem is that depending on how you installed your compiler, stuff can land in weird places.

I bet if you look, you don't have a /usr/include directory. You can do something like this:

```
find / -name stdlib.h 2>/dev/null
```

This will give you hints where the include files are. You can then chase that upwards to see if somewhere you have a symbolic link you should use.

On my Mac, I see gcc is installed in /usr/local/celler/gcc/version/c++/version... Whew. I didn't go looking for any symlinks, but I have no /usr/include.

I also have /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1...

You might fix this by manually creating a symlink from /usr/include to one of those locations. There might be a better way to do that.

Or you might want to add -I options that your IDE recognizes. You'll need those in your Makefile then.

This is one of the annoying things about programming C++ on a Mac. Stuff works, but the installations don't necessarily work straight out of the box without a few games. Or it's possible they get set up correctly, but then MacOS erases stuff if you do an OS upgrade. (I'm pretty sure that Mac was configured properly at one point, but g++ can't find include files again.).

You may also have to use clang instead of g++.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to compile a code that uses these libraries

Those are not libraries.  Those are header files, which you need to specify the include paths for the compiler to access them.

The good news is that the first four includes (stdlib.h, stdio.h, cstring, iostream) are standard headers.  The bad news is that the last include (portaudio.h) comes from [PortAudio](https://www.portaudio.com/), which is a third-party library.  Odds are you not only need to pass to your compiler the path where you installed your vended version of portaudio but you also need to pass a library to allow your build to include its library during linking.